# How do I use the REST API to upload files in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I will like to upload some files to my server. When a file is uploaded, i receive a son response. Is it possible to upload files with the REST API in codenameone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rest` API doesn't support multipart file upload. You would need to use the `MultipartRequest` class e.g.:

```
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.addData("myFileName", fullPathToFile, "text/plain")
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

See this for further details: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html